# JQuery: loop through elements with more than one css class name that share only the first class name

Tags: jquery, css, class, loops

I'm trying to use JQuery to loop through several div's with more than one class name, that all have the same first css class name and each one has a different second class name, e.g.

```
<div class="maintext blue"> </div>

<div class="maintext purple"> </div>

<div class="maintext chartreuse"> </div>

<div class="maintext puce"> </div>

<div class="maintext lime"> </div>
```

In JQuery I have tried

```
$(".mainText").each(function (i)

$(".mainText.*").each(function (i)

$(".mainText" *).each(function (i)

$(".mainText .*").each(function (i)
```

But it will not select any of the divs with class="mainText ..."

thanks for considering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('.maintext').each` instead. Class names are case-sensitive.

Comment: sorry for the typo. that is psuedo code to show what I what I am doing. my jQuery has the correct case, but still is not working at the basic selector level. $(".whatever") still does not select div class='whatever youwant' /div appreciate it,

Comment: It should be working perfectly then. Can you post more information (the context of the HTML, the context of the jQuery) so we can see potentially what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors are case sensitive. You have `maintext` in your HTML but `mainText` in the jQuery selector.

```
$('.maintext').each
```

Should work.

Comment: sorry for the typo. that is psuedo code to show what I what I am doing. my jQuery has the correct case, but still is not working at the basic selector level. $(".whatever") still does not select div class='whatever youwant' /div

appreciate it,

Comment: Yes! it looks like it worked with just the first class name as you guys said.  I found I had ended up with type="text/x-javascript" in the script tag, and once I removed it the script hit all the divs.

Comment: @omaether, that's because the browser doesn't recognise "x-javascript" so doesn't even run it. You should have `type="text/javascript"` though.

Answer (score 0):

in your question, the HTML says `maintext` and the JS uses `mainText` (capital T).